# Need automatic syntax highlighting for Pascal

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I notice that questions which are tagged as [pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal) do not get automatic syntax highlighting (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37910544/253056)). As a workaround one can add an inline tag:

```
<!-- language: lang-pascal -->
```

but this is fiddly, and it doesn't apply to source code in any answers. Would it be possible to have [pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal) questions trigger `lang-pascal` syntax highlighting somehow ?

Answer (score 14):

OK, I've enabled this. It should be effective immediately.

Comment: Thank you ! I just checked the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37910544/253056) and it does indeed appear to be working now.